# Materialize Design in XAML - does not work for custom XAML controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, custom-controls

I have the following custom control that inherits from a TextBox:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox {

    //custom properties, events and functions
}
```

It is used like so..

```
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="30" Text="TextBox" Margin="20" />
    <local:MyTextBox Width="100" Height="30" Text="12345" Margin="20" />
```

I have used the [Material Design In XAML Toolkit](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) in my project, which is working good, except that **MyTextBox** does not have that "Material Effect" with it as seen in the below screenshot.

[image: The MyTextBox does not show materialize design effect.]

What should I do to give that material design style in **MyTextBox**?

Comment: Have you added a style for MyTextBox? Visual Studio usually creates one for you in Generic.xaml, have you edited it?

Comment: Nope.. no other styles added that would override.

Comment: I thought a style was mandatory? Anyway, I'll put the reason in an answer

Comment: What I meant was I have not added any other styles myself, and yeah, I have not changed the content of Generic.xaml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Styles are applied through the property `TargetType`. When create a new type, it's not getting picked up as a `TextBox` to have the `MaterialDesignTextBox` style applied to it.

You must have a style, likely created automatically by VisualStudio in your Generic.xaml for your MyTextBox. You need to change it to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MyTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}"/>
```

So WPF knows to apply the style to `MyTextBox` types as well as `TextBox`

Comment: well, it seems VisualStudio has not created Generic.xaml in this project. I searched, and checked it manually.

Comment: How did you create your MyTextBox? Through the Visual Studio "Add New Item" > "Custom Control (WPF)"? Or did you just create a normal class and put the code in yourself? If you did it manually, Visual Studio doesn't create the relative style. In which case, you will have to add the above code yourself.

Comment: Yes, thats what I did wrong, I manually added a class instead of using VisualStudio. So I re-added it, and then added the code you mentioned in your answer. But it made no effect. Is there really a Style named `MaterialDesignTextBox`?

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. Was there an error or did it just not do anything? The MaterialDesignTextBox style is in:  MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf\Themes\MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml. I've you've included the MaterialDesignThemes.wpf\Themes\MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml then it includes a very similar line for x:Type TextBox

Comment: yes, ofcourse i have included that line. And after adding your code, it actually ran without any error. Just that Material style was not seen in output. I don't understand what's wrong!

Comment: No, I tried it that day, but the same result. I think I'll start this bit all over again. Maybe it has something to do with Application scope Styles? I am not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the textbox, the property `borderthickness (0,0,0,2)` and you get that same effect of material design!